# how to find double quote option in html select using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The select is like this:

```
<select id="id0" name="name0">
    <option value='30" size'> 30" size </option>                    
</select>
```

As you can see the select contains double quote. I need to find this option using this jquery:

```
$('#id0 option[value="30\" size"]')
```

however it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use $.escapeSelector(). 
For details see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/

Comment: You have to escape the backslash (which escapes the quote for jQuery/sizzle) in the selector with another backslash

Comment: @Andreas I tried: \\" but that doesnt work either

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kzdq5b4s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log($('#id0 option[value="30\\" size"]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id0" name="name0">
    <option value='30" size'> 30" size </option>
</select>
```